# Error: System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have this code, but when I click on one of the record in listbox I have this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

This is my code:

```
namespace CestovniPrikaz
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(Loca..Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        public Form2()
        {    InitializeComponent();
            loadlist();  }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   cmd.Connection = cn;
            loadlist();  }

        private void loadlist()
        { listBox1.Items.Clear();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "select Name from Person";
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());                  
                } }
            cn.Close(); }      

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {ListBox l = sender as ListBox;
            if (l.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedValue = l.SelectedIndex;
                txtName.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }} } }
```

The problem is probably in this line:

```
txtName.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Have you any idea please?

Comment: I copy here, because i have error: the post is mostly code...in my code i have normal ;)

Comment: Do you have any items in list box when form is loaded?

Comment: First please make sure where your error is, use the debugger for doing this.

Comment: Yes, i have all record in listbox...Loadlist is OK...

Comment: Which line is throwing the error ?

Comment: txtName.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

Comment: What do you mean it is null?

Comment: Sorry I meant (listBox1) -> `listBox1.SelectedValue` ... Arghhhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
txtName.Text = l.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the issue.

```
listBox1.SelectedValue = l.SelectedIndex;
txtName.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

`SelectedValue` is null and you're calling `ToString` which throws the exception. Why not just do

```
txtName.Text = l.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

Also, you're calling `listBox1` directly as well as using `l` (`listBox1.SelectedValue = l.SelectedIndex;`). They both reference the same ListBox.

Comment: You say `txtName.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();` is throwing the exception. I assume you have a TextBox called `txtName` (otherwise it wouldn't compile), so the problem lies with `l` or `SelectedValue`. Considering that `listBox1.SelectedValue = l.SelectedIndex;` didn't throw the exception, it can't be `l` that's null. Therefore, only `SelectedValue` is null and you're calling ToString on it. If you use `txtName.Text = l.SelectedIndex.ToString();` does that still throw the exception?